# Find ln(0.2) accurate to 0.001

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I want to find ln(0.2) accurate to 0.001. I get ln(1+(-0.8)) to solve the question. When I find the remainder I get the below one.

[image: Formula]

So I should find n for find ln(0.2). I find n=23 using a calculator by adding more values. I want to find it without adding more values. I want a mathematical method to find n.

Comment: Just wondering: which integrals and what is the n-value? Do you mean standard penetration resistance? If so: Would you please rephrase your question in some mathematical terms?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: If $\left|\int_0^{-\frac{98}{100}} \frac{\left(\frac{98}{100}+t\right)^n}{(1+t)^{n+1}} \, dt\right|<\frac{1}{10^6}$ then CAS says: $n>559.3659560443644309117850783700051774834$

Comment: I edit the question

Answer (score 1):

$0.2 \mathrm{e}$ is closer to $1$ than is $0.2 \mathrm{e}^2$ and $\ln(0.2 \mathrm{e}) = \ln(0.2) + 1$.  The partial sums in the alternating Taylor series for $\ln(1+x)$ bracket the value of $\ln(0.2 \mathrm{e})$ by less than $10^{-3}$ in $7$ terms.

If you permit yourself finer powers of $\mathrm{e}$ than just integer powers, you can accelerate convergence magnificently.  For instance, applying the above to $\ln(0.2 \mathrm{e}^{\frac{37}{23}})$ yields the result in one term.  Of course, one reasonably asks why you believe you can evaluate rational powers of $\mathrm{e}$ any more easily than evaluating these logarithms.

Answer (score -2):

Finally I could get answer to Remainder. After that, How to find n??
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdUep.jpg